# How to make a curve in UITableView Section Header iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have made a parallax View in which there is a Google Map and a Table View.

I am using [this](https://github.com/toandk/DTTableView) Parallax Library.

All I want is to place a curve image in the section header to make it look like this.

[image]

I have tried it with `tableHeaderView` but in that case It also scrolled with Table View.

Then I tried it with `viewForHeaderInSection`. Now when I reach at the top the my header become fixed and table scrolls.

But now the issue is I can see the cell behind the curved image.

[image]

Comment: Try to set your header view's background to something different from clearColor

Comment: I can't set any color becuase I have to make visible clear curve

Comment: So your cells should scroll right under the map?

Comment: @DennisPashkov No.. Over the Map

Comment: What if you put the map with a curve under the table view. And then apply contentInset.top property on the table view.